# How to extract json data?

Tags: android

*I am getting this trouble?*

```
[
{
    "username": "apap",
    "status": "",
    "log": "",
    "email": "apap@gmail.com",
    "lat": "",
    "dob": "5-11-1986"
},
{
    "username": "apapp",
    "status": "",
    "log": "",
    "email": "apapp@gmail.com",
    "lat": "",
    "dob": "5-11-1986"
}
],
"returncode": "0"
}
```

**Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {"incircle": at response of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray**

*For extracting incircle array value,I am writing following code:*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView username;
TextView email;
TextView dob;
TextView lat;
TextView log;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> jsonlist;
JsonAdapter objAdapter;
Context ctx;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
            .getJSONfromURL("http://www.railsboxtech.com/flirtalert/alluser.php");

    try {

        JSONArray flirt = json.getJSONArray("response");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "namr", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        for (int i = 0; i < flirt.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject ei = flirt.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray eie = ei.getJSONArray("incircle");
            for (int j = 0; j < eie.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject e = eie.getJSONObject(j);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("User",e.getString("username"));
                map.put("Email",e.getString("email"));
                map.put("dob",e.getString("dob"));
                map.put("lat",e.getString("lat"));
                map.put("log",e.getString("log"));
                jsonlist.add(map);

            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, jsonlist, R.layout.user_list,
            new String[] { "User", "Email","dob","lat","log"}, new int[] {
                    R.id.username, R.id.email, R.id.dob, R.id.lat, R.id.log});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: plz post valid json because current json string is not valid

Comment: what is "this trouble"? and what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I want to extract incircle data.which is like: incircle":[{"username":"arvind","email":"arvind@gmail.com","dob":"05-11-1986","l‌​at":"23.34486","log":"79.98786","status":""},{"username":"ashish","email":"ashish‌​@gmail.com","dob":"19-09-1998","lat":"23.34486","log":"79.98786","status":""}]

Comment: ei is object of JSONObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve the elements of the array with this line

```
JSONArray ja1= eie.getJSONArray(j);
```

You require the elements to be arrays themselfs, however, in your input the elements are objects.

Since the input has only one array but your code assumes two nested arrays, you probably want something like:

```
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
        .getJSONfromURL("http://www.railsboxtech.com/flirtalert/alluser.php");

try {
    JSONObject ei = json.getJSONObject("response");
    JSONArray eie = ei.getJSONArray("incircle");
    for (int j = 0; j < eie.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject e = eie.getJSONObject(j);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("User",e.getString("username"));
        map.put("Email",e.getString("email"));
        map.put("dob",e.getString("dob"));
        map.put("lat",e.getString("lat"));
        map.put("log",e.getString("log"));
       jsonlist.add(map);
   }
} catch ...
```

Comment: So,what I need to do now as I am beginner in Android..Can you please brief it.

Comment: please show your full code and input string. It seems the error happens already in the part you have not shown.

Comment: Well I still don't know how your full JSON input string looks like. Can it be that the top level `response` field is not an array but an object?

Comment: {"response":{"returncode":"0","incircle":[{"username":"arvind","email":"arvind@gmail.com","dob":"05-11-1986","lat":"23.34486","log":"79.98786","status":""},{"username":"ashish","email":"ashish@gmail.com","dob":"19-09-1998","lat":"23.34486","log":"79.98786","status":""}]}}

Comment: What if a json array is not containing name as:{"username":"arvind","email":"arvind@g‌​mail.com","dob":"05-11-1986","lat":"23.34486","log":"79.98786","status":""},{"use‌​rname":"ashish","email":"ashish@gmail.com","dob":"19-09-1998","lat":"23.34486","l‌​og":"79.98786","status":""}

Comment: First, it must have correct array syntax `[ ... ]`, if this is your top level structure, you need a method that gives back a `JSONArray` instead of a `JSONObject`. I don't know where your `JSONfunctions` is coming from but it might have such a method.

Comment: I think without [..] we can call directly JSONArray object instead of calling JSONObject's object.